# Pycharm UI issue

Tags: user-interface, pycharm

Recently in Pycharm, some buttons, tabs started to get half painted over when hovering or selecting. Has anyone dealt with this problem and how can it be fixed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEIx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBdJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkyeM.png)

Linux, Ubuntu

I've tried changing UI themes, reinstalling Pycharm, but it didn't help :c

Answer (score 0):

For VirtualBox:
go to settings, display and disable "Extended Features: Enable 3d Acceleration"